# How to display image in onsen-ui, which link is in database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm using onsen-ui framework for developing hybrid app, Data from database is displayed perfectly but the image is not displayed while using the tag

x.image_thumb - contains whole image path 
eg. http://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/01/cute-baby.jpg.838x0_q80.jpg

Everything works well in localhost but while running on Monaca LocalKit it doesn't display anything

Json Data FROM DB

```
  [{"wid":"1","project_title":"Baby 1","project_thumb":"http://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/01/cute-baby.jpg.838x0_q80.jpg"},{"wid":"2","project_title":"Baby 2","project_thumb":"http://media.mnn.com/assets/images/2016/01/cute-baby.jpg.838x0_q80.jpg"}]
```

Script

```
      <script>
       ons.bootstrap()
        .controller('AppController', function($scope, $http) {
        this.load = function(page) {
         $scope.splitter.content.load(page);
         $scope.splitter.left.close();
        };

      this.toggle = function() {
          $scope.splitter.left.toggle();
      };


         $http.get("php_file/json.php").then(function (response) {
              $scope.staticData = response.data;
        });


      });

      </script>
```

ONS-PAGE CODE

```
       <ons-template id="staticprojects.html">
       <ons-page>
           <ons-toolbar>
              <div class="left">
                <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="app.toggle()">
                <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
             </ons-toolbar-button>
              </div>
         <div class="center">
              Images

             </div>
             </ons-toolbar>

                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                       <li ng-repeat="x in staticData track by $index" >
                             <p class="page_title">{{ x.project_thumb }} <br />  {{ x.project_title }}</p>
                    <img ng-src= "{{ x.project_thumb }}" width="100%"/> 
                     </li>
                 </ul>

             </ons-page>
        </ons-template>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made sure your "php_file/json.php" got hosted correctly and also is that accessible by your Monaca Localkits?

Comment: Ya php_file/json.php works in localhost

Comment: while running Monaca Localkit json content can be accessible by console log

Comment: Did you whitelist the image url? Some platforms may block cross domain requests